# Playing offline saved video of youtube in a Webview

Tags: android

I am currently working on an android app which has a webview and play online video using youtue url when network is available, but now I want to play the saved offline video( which is a new feature of youtube) from webview when there is no network availabe. Is there any way to play saved offline YouTube video in our WebView?? Can anyone help me. Please.

Comment: are you asking for suggestion...or did you try out something?

Comment: I want to get the same saved offline video feature of youtube in my webview. i am asking for a suggestion, I don't know whether it possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

There is sample how to enable caching in WebView:

```
WebView webView = new WebView( context );
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize( 5 * 1024 * 1024 ); // 5MB
webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath( getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() );
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess( true );
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled( true );
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled( true );
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT ); // load online by default

if ( !isNetworkAvailable() ) { // loading offline
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK );
}

webView.loadUrl( "http://www.google.com" );
```

There is no ExoPlayer arround, which is used by original Youtube app, which support caching. you may try to use it too.

Comment: I have tried this code already, but it didnt meet my needs. its a code for just showing the last loaded page in the browser(by default) when network is not availabe..right?

Comment: it set cache to 5mb, something like this.

Answer (score 0):

youcan not directly play that video in your app but if you wants to that video you must have to root your device to access

Comment: I have root access how can i do this?